# How Can I deploy an Apollo Sandbox in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I want to deploy a GraphQL app inside a docker container. I want to show an Apollo Sandbox in the browser, so external users can interact with it. I'm deploying a GraphQL app inside a Docker container to deploy in a external server.

If I deploy the GraphQL app in my working host, it works perfectly. I can see in the browser de Apollo Sandbox and interact with it. When I try to access it in a Docker container the browser show me an "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

This is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  gql:
    image: node:latest
    user: node
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - kn-net
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    ports:
      - 3011:3011
    command: "npm run start:gql:lib"

  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    networks:
      - kn-net
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3013:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "root"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ">7Xs,BXmvs"
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: "lionmiss"

networks:
  kn-net:
    driver: bridge
```

The index.ts of the app is the following

```js
// I have skipped the imports and the nexus ceration schema because deploying in local works without problems


//  DB config connect
setMongoose("strictQuery", true);
const promiseDB: Promise<Mongoose> = connect( `mongodb://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}?authSource=${DB_NAME}`,
  {
    user: DB_USER,
    pass: DB_USER_PASS,
  }
);
console.log( `mongodb://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}?authSource=${DB_NAME}`);

// Connect DB + Init API GQL
promiseDB
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`️  Connected to DB`);

    let plugins = [];
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      plugins = [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageProductionDefault({ embed: true, graphRef: 'myGraph@prod' })]
    } else {
      plugins = [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true })]
    }

    const server: ApolloServer = new ApolloServer({
      schema,
      plugins,
    });

    return startStandaloneServer(server, {context, listen: {port: Number(GQL_PORT), host: GQL_HOST}, });
  })
  .then(({url}: {url: string}) => console.log(`  Graphql server is ready at ${url}`))
  .catch((err: Error) => console.log("  Error Grapql server:", err));
```

In local works but not in docker... I don't know what is the problem. The container logs don't show me any problems.

Comment: What are the constants `GQL_HOST` and `GQL_PORT`?  With the setup you show, they need to be exactly host `0.0.0.0` and port `3011` or else the Docker `ports:` forwarding won't work.  (If you're going to use the unmodified `node` image and set it up to run code from the host, you might find it easier to `docker-compose up -d db` to start the database only, then run `npm run start:gql:lib` on the host.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David Maze for the answer. I realized what is the problem. If you see the `index.ts` the hostname in the config is hardcoded. I was maintaining "localhost" in the .env of the server, so that it will never works on production. Any external user will not able to access. The solution is delete the host value in the StandAlone GQL server.

Bye!